# MS Word: Proactively assign a specific style to all cross-references?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, styles, cross-reference

I found [this great question/answer on retroactively applying a specific style to all cross-references in a document](https://superuser.com/questions/13531/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-specific-style-to-all-cross-references-in-word-2007), but is there a way to define a cross-reference style proactively so that every time I create a new cross-reference within my document, it uses my defined style?

Comment: Your link is bad.

Answer (score 0):

All styles that are not specified in the document itself, take their default
value from the global document template.

This template is found in the folder `%systemdrive%\users\%username%`,
and the file is named `Normal.dotm`.

You may double-click this file, create your style, then save it.
Word will not normally let you save it over `normal.dotm`,
so you need to save as `normal2.dotm` in the same folder,
quit Word, delete `normal.dotm` and rename `normal2.dotm` as `normal.dotm`.

Save a copy of `normal.dotm` before starting, just in case.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue isn't defining the style, but having it automatically apply the style when I insert the cross-reference.  Right now, I have to insert the cross-reference, then apply the style.  This isn't ideal.  It's an extra step, and if/when a cross-reference changes, the formatting will revert back to the Word default.

Comment: This is exactly what should happen - in all documents where you didn't specify a given style, that style comes from `normal.dotm`, including for cross-reference.